# when will the closure cause performance issue

Tags: javascript, closures

Closure is a powerful tool,however it is said that it will cause performance problem if not correctly used.

So I want to know in which case it will occur?

It is better if with live examples . :)

Comment: _Anything_ can cause performance issues if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

One instance is creating them in a loop. Consider the following jQuery:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    $('#elements').click(function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

This will create a closure on each iteration. This can be easily optimized by creating the function separately:

```
function log(e) { console.log(e); }
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    $('#elements').click(log);
```

Then you are just passing a reference instead of recreating the closure repeatedly.

Comment: Is the log function a closure? I think it is just a unnamed function.

Comment: it is *not* a closure. The optimization would be to remove the use of a closure. The example is a *misuse* of closures and the fix is to not use one. Also log is a named function.

Answer (score 1):

One of the performance issue one can stumble upon when dealing with closures is too much nesting levels.

Provided functions are wrapped one in another many times, the time engine has to spend when looking up the variable used in inner function can be sometimes significant.